# How do I debug a single unit test with node-inspectror?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, debugging, node-inspector

From the excellent [node inspector docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector):

> How do I debug Mocha unit-tests?
>   You have to start _mocha as the debugged process and make sure the execution pauses on the first line. This way you have enough time to set your breakpoints before the tests are run.

```
$ node-debug _mocha
```

Which works fine to debug the whole test suite.

And I know I can **run** a single test with:

```
 mocha -g 'some expression'
```

But how do I **debug a single test** with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `node-debug` passes command-line arguments to the debugged application. You should be able to debug a single unit-test using the following command:

```
$ node-debug _mocha -g 'some expression'
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind changing your test code while debugging, you can replace `it` with `it.only` to instruct mocha to run only this particular test. With that change in place, `node-debug _mocha` should work for you too.